# Do Compilers for FPGA Languages Perform Optimizations?

Tags: verilog, compiler-optimization, fpga

One of the more useful features of modern compilers for computer languages like C/C++, Fortran, Julia, etc, is their ability to perform optimizations on the code before producing the binary. If I were to write a function in, say, Verilog to make an FPGA "hardware" special function, would the compiler perform any optimizations? As a concrete example, say I want to setup a polynomial evaluator that uses [Estrin's scheme for parallelized evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme), and some of the coefficients are 0, will the compiler see that and optimize away the effective NOOPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The optimization in your example is called "*constant propagation*". When it comes to optimizing Boolean or arithmetic expressions, the techniques are the same in all compilers. The compiler will simplify any expression it can. Another optimization is "*dead code elimination*" If a branching condition turns out to be a constant, the unchosen branches can be eliminated and the branch taken becomes unconditional.  But after RTL is converted to a hardware representation, the optimization process is very different from software compilers.

Comment: If a loop has a moderate and fixed number of iterations, will the compiler unroll it into hardware? It seems there's the potential for both a standard parallel unroll (when loops are independent) and a serial unroll (when each iteration modifies some value) with this sort of language.

Comment: _loops_ do not exist in hardware. No procedural statements exist in hardware for that matter. The way loops in RTL code get implemented in hardware is too broad a topic for this forum.

Comment: That can't be the case, can it? I'm not a hardware guy, so I could be wrong, but I can imagine that hardware should be able to implement repetition that runs whenever a decreasing counter is non-zero and a "ready for next iteration" flag is set. Are those not possible, or not practical (ie unstable) in some way?

Comment: I think we are getting into terminology nuances. Without a proper understanding of how the HDL code you write gets synthesized into a structure of AND, OR and NOT logic gates, we are not going to get very far. Although FPGA has "Programmable" in it, an FPGA does not run a compiled program like you compile software to run on a host processor.

Comment: I think I see the problem now - what I'm describing will probably, inevitably, lead to a race condition somewhere in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog has loops in generate statements, which are always fully unrolled at synthesis time.

Comment: _Any_ loop you write in Verilog, whether it be a generate-for or procedural-for has to be unrolled into hardware.